# Retrieve information Text/Word from HTML code using awk/sed

Tags: sed, awk

awk/sed newbie here. I have a HTML file and from that file and I would like to retrieve a  text word.

```
<font face=arial size=-1><li><a href=/value_for_clients/Tokyo/abc_process.txt>abc</a> NDK Version:  4.0 </li>
<font face=arial size=-1><li><a href=/value_for_clients/Tokyo/abc01_process.txt>abc01</a> NDK Version:  4.0 </li>
<font face=arial size=-1><li><a href=/value_for_clients/Tokyo/abc045_process.txt>abc045</a> NDK Version:  4.0 </li>
<font face=arial size=-1><li><a href=/value_for_clients/Tokyo/cdf_process.txt>cdf</a> NDK Version:  4.0 </li>
<font face=arial size=-1><li><a href=/value_for_clients/Tokyo/Manhattan_process.txt>Manhattan</a> NDK Version:  4.0 </li>
```

For eg. From the 1st line I would like to retrieve abc placed between: .txt>abc/a>

I have used the following command but as you can see that number of letters in the word keeps changing abc, abc01, abc045, cdf, Manhattan.

```
awk -F\/ '{print substr($4,0,3)}' list.html
```

So this command is getting the output for only the 3 letter word. However I want to extract the same information (abc01, abc045, cdf, Manhattan) from all the lines in the HTML code. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{print $7}' urls 
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
```

Comment: When I run this command I get number of lines in the html file times blank lines. Nothing gets displayed (awk -F'[<>]' '{print $7}' list.html). Same thing happens when I try to run awk command (awk -F'(txt>|</a)' '{print $2}' list.html) mentioned by John1024. Any idea?

Comment: What is your OS and version of awk? Does it work if you just copy the code you pasted above into a file: that is what we did...

Comment: I am running this from Solaris 10. "Copy the code you pasted above into the file"? Would you like me to copy "awk -F'[<>]' '{print $7}' list.html" into the file and execute it from there ?

Comment: No: I was trying to ascertain if your source data was any different from what you posted in your question.

Comment: No it is not different. In fact again I just tried copying the code I mentioned above to a new file and ran it but still I am getting 5 blank lines. So it is running something but no output is displayed.

Comment: I don't know anything about Solaris, but you could test that it is not a different field by using `{print $1}` instead...

Comment: This command worked for me "sed 's#.*txt>##;s#<.*##' file.html". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
perl -nE '/<a href.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/; say $1' file
```

Output:

```
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*txt>\([[:alnum:]]\+\)<.*/\1/p' list.html
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
```

Or:

```
$ awk -F'(txt>|</a)' '{print $2}' list.html
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
```

Answer (score 1):

I use command **`sed`** or **`awk`** to extract it. Here, I save origin data into file `/tmp/html.txt`.

Both of them utilize *regular expression* and *back reference*

#### Via sed

```
flying@lempstacker:~$ sed -r -n 's@.*<a [^>]*>(.*)</a>.*@\1@p' /tmp/html.txt
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
flying@lempstacker:~$
```

#### Via awk

using function [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
flying@lempstacker:~$ awk '{print gensub(/.*<a [^>]*>(.*)<\/a>.*/,"\\1"," ",$0)}' /tmp/html.txt
abc
abc01
abc045
cdf
Manhattan
flying@lempstacker:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu grep

```
grep -Po "<a href.*?>\K[^<]*" file
```